# Speech does not exist under the namespace System: Even under Wine with .NET Framework

Tags: .net, mono, text-to-speech, wine, speech-synthesis

I know Speech doesn't exist under System in Mono because Mono lacks SAPI, but the same error occurs when using the .NET Framework (4.0) with Wine.

Is there a way around this?  (I hoped I was being clever. :/)

For reference, my Dockerfile: https://github.com/stephenwithav/docker-wine/blob/master/Dockerfile

Example speech code for testing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.setoutputtowavestream(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: A way around this OTHER than using Windows. ;)

Comment: Surely you forgot to add a reference to System.Speech.dll

Comment: Not sure if you're ridiculing my use of links or not, but... [actual](https://gist.github.com/stephenwithav/ca3d2210b831921e3246d6521537f745) code.

Comment: So you have no idea what "add a reference" means.  Well, that's going to take work.  Start by googling ".net how to add a reference".

Comment: I [do now](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21544201/1513211), ty!  now it's giving me a CS0006 error, file not found.  probably because I'm giving it a linux path vs a virtual c: path.

Comment: Correct assumption.  Now it's failing due to no voices being found. ([log](http://pastebin.com/4wrjqd1i)) Any suggestions?