# IGrouping Not Found in Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.0

I've done a **GroupBy** using `Linq` as follows in a controller:

```cs
model.aLstProducts = result[0].Results
    .Where(c => c.Id == ProductId)
    .ToList()
    .FirstOrDefault()
    .ListOfProducts
    .GroupBy(c => c.ProductCategory);
```

The property has been defined as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, ProductsViewModel>> aLstProducts { get; set; }
```

When I try to use it in the front-end using `Razor`, it throws the following exception:

```cs
@foreach (var item in Model.aLstProducts)
{ 
}
```

**Error**:

> The type 'IGrouping<,>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

What could be the reason for the above or how can I overcome it?

**N.B**: I can work with generic `List` in the `Razor` view but for the **GroupBy** getting the exception.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a reference to assembly in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21543093/how-to-add-a-reference-to-assembly-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of razor page add

```
@model IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, ProductsViewModel>>
```

then loop through the Model

```
  @foreach (var item in Model)
  {     
      // your code goes here    
  }
```

Comment: This is what I get - The type or namespace name **IGrouping** couldn't be found.

Answer (score 0):

use System.Linq at razor as well.
[ms doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2?view=net-7.0)